# How about sending and receiving List<stream> images to server in wcf?

Tags: c#, image, wcf, stream

Hi am using WCF to upload and Download images(stream images) to and from server. Currently am uploading and downloading Only one image at a time, because while sending 100's of images at a same time may cause some timout issue and all. I think this is not a better way that sending and receiving one image at a time.

Can i upload multiple images as List as well as download at the same time?

Comment: If you use streaming, WCF only supports one stream per operation contract (at least of of the box), so a list of streams won't work. Why dont you upload  the files in parallel?

Comment: @FlorianGerhardt parallel in the sense of? calling service parallelly?

Comment: Yes, start multiple uploads at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable streaming if you are using BasicHttpBinding, NetTcpBinding, NetNamedPipebinding or WebHttpBinding.

```
<system.serviceModel>
     …
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ExampleBinding" transferMode="Streaming"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
     …
<system.serviceModel>
```

Check out this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)